# How to hide background grid lines in live chart?

Tags: c#, winforms, livecharts

I am using live charts for my winform application graph. In this I want to hide background grid lines based on user action. Is there any default option for that ?

www.lvcharts.net

Comment: `<lvc:Separator StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#8EFFFFFF" StrokeDashArray="8" Step="100" />` Tried setting `StrokeThickness` to zero?

Comment: I am using winforms here. Is there any property in winforms to set the stroke thickness ?

Comment: You should use intellisense of VS to figure out the separator of the Axis and StrokThinkness property of the Seperator...

Comment: Example code `var yAxis = new Axis
            {
                Separator = new Separator
                {
                    StrokeThickness = 0
                }
            };

            cartesianChart1.AxisY.Add(yAxis);`

Comment: https://github.com/Live-Charts/Live-Charts/tree/master/Core

Comment: Thanks chetan. It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by adjusting strokethickness of the graph. As shown below :

```
cartesianChart.AxisX[0].Separator.StrokeThickness = 0;
cartesianChart.AxisY[0].Separator.StrokeThickness = 0;
```